# padding problem in sha-1 hashed password

Tags: decryption, encoding

For my own understanding of Websphere LTPA keys, I'm running [this Java code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wr330/escmp-git/a98b3fe5ce2a569d8e1ec4e0d2136a900928dfe3/src/com/zcore/sso/LtpaToken.java), which works correctly when using the author's Base64 encoded, SHA1 hashed password:

```
String ltpa3DESKey = "IpGJOdpSxV3J8yWAuB+UiUlYCK7sAzSfENE5MLT2q+s=";
```

but fails when using mine:

```
String ltpa3DESKey = "ExGKSrGQPGN+q0GE1GlFhK7BB8bLB0mEp9ec1Vzxv8A\=";
```

Error:

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

But if I escape it:

```
String ltpa3DESKey = "ExGKSrGQPGN+q0GE1GlFhK7BB8bLB0mEp9ec1Vzxv8A\=";
```

I get:

```
 javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:991)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineDoFinal(DESedeCipher.java:294)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at com.me.ltpa.LtpaToken.decrypt(LtpaToken.java:79)
    at com.me.ltpa.LtpaToken.getSecretKey(LtpaToken.java:62)
    at com.me.ltpa.LtpaToken.decryptLtpaToken(LtpaToken.java:110)
    at com.me.ltpa.LtpaToken.getInstance(LtpaToken.java:118)
    at com.me.ltpa.LtpaToken.main(LtpaToken.java:139)
```

I've read the basics of the Base64 Wikipedia article, but apparently backslashes aren't part of the Base64 alphabet. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: The tool you used to base64 encode the key should not have generated a backslash. Re-encode the key with a better encoder. (see CyberChef for a good all purpose encoding tool.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different variants of base64 encoding; while none I know of should produce a \, you might be better off just to use a URL-compatible version (which is done in java [like the first google hit says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633402/java-encode-and-decode-string-without-forward-or-backward-slash)).

Obiter Dictum:

- There is usually no good reason to use 3DES and not AES. 3DES has long been deprecated.
- Sha1 is not a good key derivation function, please use one that is designed for this purpose, like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

Comment: I never finished this project, but the code I'm testing is old and corresponds to when 3DES was the industry standard, so I'm moving on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Guess Java tries to identify the \ as an commandin the String, like e.g. \n.
There's no command like \=, so that's why the exception appears.
I would recommand you to put some // instead of \ , otherwise you might not use the \ for your strings.